# Overuse of pronouns

Tags: formality, sequence-of-tenses

In the paragraph:
"Company with 8 years of commercial experience, they are in the growth stage within the primary sector of the economy, they have a workforce of approximately 200 employees, additionally, they reported hiring up to 5,000 temporary workers in high season, aspect that positions them as a medium company. Their sales area is national and international,   performing foreign trade activity with the United States, Asia, South America, Switzerland, Spain and Germany."

Am i overusing the pronoun "they"?,

Comment: Note that it can be quite subjective if a pronoun is overused or not. In a given sentence, some people might say that it is, while others might say that it isn't. There is no objective *rule* that determines this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: Per the grammatical rules of English, there is no limit on using the pronoun, so long as the pronoun's antecedent(what the pronoun is referring to) is clear.

However, some might complain that the pronoun "they" is overused here, because in a situation like this, it is a more usual practice to combine this many sentences* into one or more compound sentences. There is a tradition of using multiple short sentences for emphasis through repetition, especially in an accusatory fashion, but it is a less common format to use used.

*Your first sentence is a run-on sentence. This can be fixed by either:
1) Replacing the commas with periods to break it up into multiple sentences(except for the comma after additionally).

> [The] Company [has] 8 years of commercial experience. They are in the growth stage within the primary sector of the economy. They have a workforce of approximately 200 employees. Additionally, they reported hiring up to 5,000 temporary workers in high season. [This] aspect positions them as a medium company.

2) Using conjunctions to create a compound sentence (in which case the repeated pronouns are redundant and unnecessary)

> The Company, with 8 years of commercial experience, are in the growth stage within the primary sector of the economy, and have a workforce of approximately 200 employees, with up to an additional 5,000 temporary workers hired in high season, which positions them as a medium company.